# ASP.net Calender DayRender show multiple text responses per day

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar

I've got a simple asp.net calender which highlights and enters the users name on the days  they have requested a holiday. However the newest request overwrites the name of the old request rather than showing multiple names. The code as follows:

```
  Protected Sub Calendar1_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs) _
        Handles Calendar1.DayRender
    Dim nextDate As DateTime
    Dim StartDate As DateTime
    Dim Enddate As DateTime
    Dim username As String

    If Not dsHolidays Is Nothing Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In dsHolidays.Tables(0).Rows
            StartDate = CType(dr("StartDate"), DateTime)
            Enddate = CType(dr("EndDate"), DateTime)
            nextDate = CType(dr("startdate"), DateTime)
            username = CType(dr("username"), String)

            If e.Day.Date >= StartDate And e.Day.Date <= Enddate Then

                e.Cell.Text = username
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not appending the username to the cell text. To display a list of the user names, change the line  **e.Cell.Text = username** to  **e.Cell.Text += username**.

One alternative would be to add controls to the cell dynamically (e.g. **e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(username**));) instead of simply displaying the text.

This should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks... e.Cell.Text += username worked fine...anyway I could get them to display on separate rows/paragraph? It currently displays one directly after another

Comment: yeah - just change it to e.Cell.Text += username + "<br />" or however you want it to display. If you want to get fancy, you could add a new table control to the cell and add each username as a cell in that table.